# iCloud Drive keeps re-downloading a 40GB file

Tags: icloud, storage

I am running the macOS Big Sur Beta. Every little while, iCloud Drive will randomly start to download 50GB of files I don't need. I have a ~40GB zip file full of photos that I do not need stored on my laptop and this keeps downloading. This is wasting a lot of data. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Isn't that the desired behavior of iCloud Drive? Keeping a copy of your files on your Mac for offline access? The only way to prevent that (to some extent) is to configure your Mac to keep only your recent files: choose Apple menu  > System Preferences > iCloud and turn on Optimize Mac Storage. See "Store your files in iCloud and save space on your device" section at https://support.apple.com/HT206985 for more information.

Comment: iCloud is not a storage solution, it is a synchronisation solution. It is not designed to keep backups. if you want data to be only stored online, look into Dropbox or similar.

Comment: I wish they would advertise it that way, though. Not fun to find this out after having uploaded a terabyte of data into it and then randomly having the disk full because it decided to "sync" something... despite the name it is not a serious cloud drive service, one should look elsewhere for those.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that appears to be 'fixed', based on the description in your question.

The purpose of iCloud is give you access to your data from any device logged-in with the same Apple ID. Using iCloud, you can access photos, files, contacts, Safari tabs, etc, just like they were part of your file system.  For example, if you create a doc using Pages on your Mac you can access and edit that same file from your iPad using the Pages app.

It looks like iCloud is simply syncing data between your devices at a regular interval.  This is normal, expected behavior.  You can control what's synced by going into your Apple ID via Settings on any logged-in device.

If you only want a backup solution, you can look into other services such as Dropbox and OneDrive.